# send js variable through iframe?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, iframe

I have an image upload which uses an iframe + php to uplaod the image + show it on the page without refreshing (sort of as a preview).

I want to be able to send a variable (which will always be an integer, its an auto increment mysql ID) to the iframe and php script, so that any edits/ re-uploads etc will affect the same table row as before.

so to clarify:

1. I have a integer stored in a js variable
2. on 'change' of the file input, i need to somehow send this variable via the iframe to the php script, where the php script can interpret and use it.

**EDIT:**

heres some stripped down version of my code to help explain. First, the actual page with the file input:

```
<form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="last-id-test.php" target="upload_target">
<input name="file" id="file" size="27" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" /><br />
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #c9cfdd;"></iframe>
</form>
```

so when the form is submitted, it uses the last-id-test.php script to do the actual uploading/ inserting into database, but does it via its target iframe, 'upload_target' to avoid page re-load.

-some php stuff happens, but I get the mysqli_insert_id() of the upload and send it back to the page, where it is stored in the 'insertID' variable:

```
function uploadDone() { //Function will be called when iframe is loaded
var returnedValues = frames['upload_target'].document.getElementsByTagName("body") [0].innerHTML.split('@');
insertID = returnedValues[0];
imgName = returnedValues[1];
makeImage =$('<img>').attr('src','images/listing-images/'+imgName);

makeImage.appendTo($('#image-preview'));
}
```

here I also add a preview of the image.

So how do I send the insertID variable to the php script on 'change' of the file input?

Comment: we cant help you based on unknown code!

Comment: can you store the variable in the session and set/retrieve it via AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Send it as a query variable, such as `/viewImage.php?image_id=123`

In PHP you can read these query variable as `$_GET['image_id']`

Answer (score 0):

i achieved this with a hidden input, generated dynamically and setting its value attribute to the returned insertID variable:

```
function uploadDone() { //Function will be called when iframe is loaded
var returnedValues = frames['upload_target'].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML.split('@');
var insertID = returnedValues[0];
var imgName = returnedValues[1];
var makeImage =$('<img>').attr('src','images/listing-images/'+imgName);

makeImage.appendTo($('#image-preview'));

var makeInput = $('<input>').attr('type','hidden').attr('id','insertID').attr('value',insertID).attr('name','insertID');

makeInput.appendTo($('#file_upload_form'));
}
```

Comment: Be aware that if you plan to run this function multiple times on the same page, you will be adding a new hidden input each time, without removing the previous.  Since they all have the same ID, the effects will be undefined.  You might want to either 1) create the hidden input in the html (php) and just set its value in the uploadDone fn, or 2) have a check in the uploadDone function that it doesn't exist before creating it.  (And if it does, just update the value.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ajax to submit the form? If so, you can just pass the variable using the onclick function.

This may be helpful
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/